# Why does 2018 have fewer hats than 2017 - Winter Bash

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Looking at the 2017 post:

*[Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats)*

And 2018:

*[Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list)*

I realized that 2017 had many more hats. Why?

There are much fewer currently (2018) than 2017(??).

So they're being removed. My questions are:

> Why are so many hats removed from 2017 winter bash?

---

> How do those hats get removed?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320250/are-hats-different-every-winter-bash

Comment: @RobertLongson IS it really a dupe :-)

Comment: No, it's a cross site question/answer so it can't be a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each year has its own list of hats; hats don't get 'removed'. A successful/popular hat might be chosen again the next year, but there is no guarantee.

Note that we haven't discovered all secret hats for 2018 yet; most likely there will be one for participating on Christmas and/or the Winter Solstice.

Comment: Thanks, that's true, useful one man...